# How to get rid of extra space on the footer?

Tags: css

I am currently working on a footer for my website and whenever I put something inside of the footer class there seems to be some space below everything that I am unsure on how to get rid of. I would just like the footer to be 'cut' or end after my elements that are inside of it.

You can view my website that I am referring to live [here](http://www.heartfx.org).
The extra space that I am referring to is [here](http://prntscr.com/6g1o4a).

*footer.php*

```
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer_elements">
            <div class="useful_resources">
                <h1>Useful Resources</h1>
                    <p><a href="index.php">home</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">graphics</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">web</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">contact</a></p>
            </div>
            <?php include 'includes/modules/connect.php' ?>
            <?php include 'includes/modules/newsletter.php' ?>

        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

*Styles.css* :

```
.footer{width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 20px; margin-top: -50px; border-bottom: 30px solid #23262B;}
.footer_elements{font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;}
.footer_elements h1{font-size: 26px;}
.footer_elements p{font-size: 18px;}
.footer_elements p{margin-top: -10px;}
.useful_resources{padding: 35px; color: white; float: left;}
.useful_resources a{color: white; text-decoration: none;}
.useful_resources a:hover{color: #CC7A29;}

.connect{padding: 35px; color: white; overflow: hidden;}
.connect a{color: white; text-decoration: none;}
.connect img{width: 35px; float: left; margin-top: -2px;}
.connect_bg{background-color: #393C40; border: 0px solid white; border-radius: 7px; max-width: 225px;}
.connect_bg:hover{background-color: #7AA3CC;}
.connect_bg p{padding: 5px;}
.connect_bg2{background-color: #393C40; border: 0px solid white; border-radius: 7px; max-width: 225px;}
.connect_bg2:hover{background-color: #1F5C99;}
.connect_bg2 p{padding: 5px;}
.connect_bg3{background-color: #393C40; border: 0px solid white; border-radius: 7px; max-width: 225px;}
.connect_bg3:hover{background-color: red;}
.connect_bg3 p{padding: 5px;}
.connect_bg3 img{margin-top: -7px;}
.connect_bg4{background-color: #393C40; border: 0px solid white; border-radius: 7px; max-width: 225px;}
.connect_bg4:hover{background-color: #FF99CC;}
.connect_bg4 p{padding: 5px;}

.newsletter {margin-left: 25px; padding: 15px; width: 500px; border: 2px dashed white; border-radius: 30px; background-color: #393C40; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; color: white; max-width: 600px; }
.newsletter:hover{background-color: #1F5C99;}
.newsletter p{font-size: 14px; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: -35px;}
.heading{margin-left: 125px;}
```

If anymore details are needed I can provide them. Thank you in advance to anyone that has a possible solution to the extra space in the footer.

Best regards,
Codi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think that the extra space you are refering to is caused by your div with the class "square". Its height attribute, "100%", is adding the total height of the original page to the bottom.

Comment: This seemed to fix it for the most part, just had to do few more tweaks in the css as well to finally get it functioning the way it was suppose to in all resolutions as well. Thanks!